# How to use RTCMultiConnection on Ruby/Python/PHP or similar platforms?

Tags: rtcmulticonnection

[RTCMultiConnection](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RTCMultiConnection) seems using socket.io (node.js) based solution.

**How to integrate** RTCMultiConnection into **ruby-on-rails** (or PHP/Python/ASP.NET/MVC/etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. You can setup a separate ipAddress/domain for node.js.
> 2. Or you can use same domain however run node.js on a separate port e.g. 9001.
> 3. Your PHP/Ruby/Python/ASPX pages can internally use/link that node.js/socket.io server.

Use `nohup` command to keep running [server.js](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RTCMultiConnection#keep-running-server-in-background) in the background.

Now copy/paste any of the [RTCMultiConnection demo](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RTCMultiConnection/tree/master/demos) **in your Ruby/PHP pages.**

1. **Make sure that `socket.io.js` is having a valid URL**

   `<script src="https://your-domain.com:9001/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`
2. **Make sure that `socketURL` property is having valid socket.io server link/reference**

   `connection.socketURL = 'https://your-domain.com:9001/';`

Now you can use [any demo](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RTCMultiConnection/tree/master/demos) on your Ruby/PHP/Python/etc. pages.

---

**PS.** *Chrome requires HTTPs-privileges for audio/video/screen capturing. So please make sure that your domain is having SSL installed.*